# How is opamp gain calculated in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, gain

How do I calculate the gain on each stage in [this circuit](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/2236)?

I see a feedback but no Rg.

[image]

---

So here's the simulation of the fist stage of the above circuit (Replaced the MAX4477 by a LT1395). Thanks guys, learned a lot about active filters in the past hours.

[image]

Comment: The output device is listed specifically by Maxim as a comparator: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/amplifiers/MAX987.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gain of **each stage**

IC1a - there is a 10M feedback resistor. Normally you would expect to find a series resistor to the input, to give you a pure ratio Rf/Rg gain. However, the output of the photodiode is a *current*. This stage gives you volts out for current in, which has dimensions of resistance, not a pure ratio. In this case, the transimpedance is 10Mohms, 10v out for 1uA in.

IC1b, 2a, 2b - each has an Rg of 1k, and Rf of 10k, so the DC gain of each stage is 10. The Cs provide some bandpass filtering.

IC3 is a comparator, with very high gain around the threshhold point (zero gain at other input voltages), you will need to look at the data sheet for that.

Comment: Comparators have gain? Damn. Any source for this? or are you talking about Open loop Gain?

Comment: @ammar.cma All gain starts as open loop gain. An opamp has linear gain created by using feedback to modify the OLG. A comparator also has nominally infinite OL gain. It CAN be reduced with feedback if there is a good reason to do so but usually a comparator is run OL, as here. It's common to give a comparator POSITIVE feedback which produces hysteresis.

Answer (score 1):

Those are opamps, but the caption below the image clearly says:

> Figure 1. When a single gamma photon with sufficient energy strikes the PIN Photodiode in this circuit, the output of the comparator pulses high.

So, they're not all *used* as things with a constant gain, at least IC3 is just used as a comparator.

The other ones are used as active filters. So the whole input resistance/feedback resistance formula typically still applies, but you need to consider it for the the complex-valued impedances these resistor/cap pairs pose.

There's plenty of literature out there on active filters based on opamps, I'd really recommend reading any one of these :)

Comment: So it's basically open-loop gain with filter characteristic?

Comment: Yes, you only need to look at the last opamp/comparator (IC3), notice that it **has no feedback**. So the **overall** gain will be very high.

Comment: I see. I'm not particularly interested in the output of this circuit. I was looking for a fast, low noise, high gain light pulse amplifier (LIDAR) and thought i could adapt the first stage of this one.

Comment: attention: the filters and these specific opamps don't have "very high" bandwidth, and that is intentional. You need to match the filter response to what you're doing; analog.com has an active filter designer that might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the active filter designer. The pulse width is 40ns and the goal resolution 10m, I think that's not yet in the  voodoo range. Should be doable with a faster amp.

Comment: pulse width = 40ns implies a bandwidth above 25 MHz; these are the regions you need to start taking HF circuitry guidelines into account, please don't forget. You'll need high-bandwidth opamps.

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual.
Without a gamma triggered pulse all 4477 stages are unity gain DC followers and vout all settles to Vdivider high.
IC3 noninverting is set to very slightly lower dcv by the 10k pot. So IC3 out is low. When a pulse occurs stages have gains of about 1 10 10 10 or 1000 overall. This is rolled off by parallel caps across fb resistors and increased with frequently by coupling caps. That may have a formal BP transfer function but do not need to see it that way.

R1 probably largely sets stage 1 gain as reverse biased diode imp is v hi.
If pot is set for 1 unit of headroom then a pulse of 1/1000  of that will trigger output high.
Look up Ibias and Voffsets for amps to see how close pot can be set.

If pot was set to 10mV then vswing needed = 10 mV/ 1000 or 10 uV.
This in 10 M needs I change of 10 uV/10 M = 1 Pico amp. 
Or 1 nA for 10 V swing.
Ie you don't need much.